# How to stop a dispatchtimer in the viewmodel when the view is closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, timer

I want to close the timer inside of my ViewModel when the view is closed.

My code:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new UnitViewModel();

    Console.WriteLine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
}
```

**UnitViewModel.cs:**

```
class UnitViewModel : ObservableObject
{
     DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
     public UnitViewModel()
     {
          StartTimer();
     }

     private void StartTimer()
     {
          dispatcherTimer.Tick += new 
              EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
          dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 600);
          dispatcherTimer.Start();
     }

     private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          UpdateUnit();
     }
}
```

Is there a way to stop this timer when the `MainWindow` is closed? Or is not opened anymore. I prefer to have this code in my view model, is there a good way to solve this problem within MVVM?

Comment: The view model should expose a Shutdown method that stops the timer. The method should be called from a Closed or Closing event handler in MainWindow.

Answer (score 2):

Add a public API of some kind to the view model that stops the timer:

```
public void Stop() => dispatcherTimer.Stop();
```

Call this method from the view one way or another.

You could for example handle an event or override a method in the code-behind:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);
    (DataContext as UnitViewModel)?.Stop();
}
```

...or use an `EventTrigger` in the XAML markup that invokes a command:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StopCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Both approaches comply with the MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass your window to ViewModel and bind Closing event to OnClosing method:

```
public class UnitViewModel
{
    public UnitViewModel(Window w)
    {
        mainWindow = w;
        mainWindow.Closing += OnMainWindowClosing;
    }

    private Window mainWindow;

    private void OnMainWindowClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        //anything else you want
    }
}
```

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new UnitViewModel(MainWindow);
    Console.WriteLine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
}
```

Comment: "*pass your window to ViewModel*" is not MVVM. A view model does not know a view, and it does of course not know any specific events of a view like Closing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use a dispatcher timer in a viewmodel at all.
I'd probably use async and a loop instead.
The 600 ms delay would be introduced by

```
await Task.Delay(600);
```

And that would go in a while loop of whatever best suits.

I'd also work viewmodel first in a single window app so the view would be templated from that viewmodel. Dispose the viewmodel and the view goes away.

If it absolutely must be a separate window with the viewmodel then make the viewmodel a private member of that view. Close the window and the viewmodel is disposed.  Decouple the viewmodel from any model using weak reference/event if necessary.
Often my model is a web api though.